# How to save an object in mySql database?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I have a problem when saving object in the database the error is : could not execute statement;

```
SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

and code is

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/saveeeee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelAndView doSave(
   @RequestParam("user_id") String user_id, 
   @RequestParam("username") String username,
   @RequestParam("password") String password,
   @RequestParam("rol") String rol){
     ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/utilisateurs");
     User op;
     op = new User();

     Role ro;
     ro = new Role();

     ro.setRole(rol);
     ro.setUsername(username);


     if(!user_id.isEmpty()){
         op =(User)appRepo.findOne(Integer.parseInt(user_id));
     } else {
         op = new User();
     }

     op.setUsername(username);
     op.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(password));
     op.setRo(ro);

     appRepo.save(op);
     return mv;
  }
```

Comment: Please specify the database table schema

Comment: What is the rest of the exception? One of your required fields is null.

Answer (score 0):

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`stat_tn`.`user_roles`, CONSTRAINT `fk_username` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES `users` (`username`))